# CSS selectors for styling the word "bar"

Tags: css, css-selectors

A question the instructor asked during a lecture:

Which CSS selector will select only the word "bar" for styling?

```
<p class="a">foo, <span class="a">bar</span></p>
```

1. `span.a`
2. `p .a`
3. `.a  span`
4. All of these

The answer given was (4).

(1) is obvious because only `bar` (and not `foo`) can affected by a `span` selector with class `a`, but (2) and (3) are less obvious. Would someone break down what is happening in each case?

Comment: you have .a .a{}  too :)

Comment: Please read about [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors), and build the courage to ask your lecturers: we're happy to help, but if your lecturer introduced the syntax he should have explained it. Unless that was your homework.

Comment: @David_Thomas This is an online MOOC course on edX. I am taking it for my own education and not for credit. I watched recorded lectures of the instructor speaking so was unable to ask any questions.

Comment: I seriously don't know why this question is down voted

Comment: People, please refrain from downvoting questions because they are basic.

Comment: @MightyPork paying attention to classes and not understanding the concept are two completely different things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me elaborate each for you

`span.a` - This will select all the `span` tags in a document having class `a`

`p.a` - This will select all the `p` elements having class `a`

`p .a` - This will select all the elements having class `a` nested under `p`

`.a span` - This will select all the `span` tag nested under class `a`

Explaining your case

```
<p class="a">foo, <span class="a">bar</span></p>
```

`a.span` will change the bar color as it selects the span tag having class `a`

`p.a` will also change the bar color, as it is nested inside `p` tag having class of `a`. Hence `span` tag will inherit the color. (Also, I would like to point out here, this selector will change the color of `foo` as well)

`p .a` will select the bar as well, as the `span` tag having class `a` is nested under `p`

`.a span` will also apply color to the bar word as `span` is nested under a tag having class `a`

---

So technically answer is ALL OF THESE WILL CHANGE THE BAR COLOR

Answer (score 3):

All of the above is the correct answer, because:

```
span.a        /* Selects all span elements with class 'a' */
p .a          /* Selects all child elements of p that have class 'span' */
.a span       /* Selects all child span elements of elements with class 'a' */
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent and child relationship. In all of these you are choosing the parent and navigating throught to the first child. If you had a list you would have to navigate through selectors with a nth child selector.

Comment: Not necessarily the first child, but rather: All childs that matches the selector.

Answer (score 0):

It is all pretty straight forward, here is an english walk through of the interpretation for CSS:

2) find `<p>` (the line), then inside `<p>` use `class="a"`, so that's  `<span class="a">bar</span>`
3) find `class="a"` and then inside of it `<span>`

Comment: You shouldn't use "<a>" to represent the class "a"

Comment: @bengoesboom I ment class, typed `<a>` fixed before you commented actually ;)